# How many objects is "too many" for in a single transaction to Google's DataStore (High Replication)?

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have following entity (non-relevant fields/methods are removed).

```
public class HitsStatsTotalDO
{
    @Id
    transient private Long targetId;

    public Key<HitsStatsTotalDO> createKey()
    {
        return new Key<HitsStatsTotalDO>(HitsStatsTotalDO.class, targetId);
    }
}
```

So... I'm trying to do batch get for 10 objects for which I construct keys using `HitsStatsTotalDO.createKey()`. I'm attempting to fetch them in transaction like this:

```
final List<Key<HitsStatsTotalDO>> keys = ....

// This is being called in transaction..
Map<Key<HitsStatsTotalDO>, HitsStatsTotalDO> result = DAOBase.ofy().get(keys);
```

which throws following exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: operating on too many entity groups in a single transaction.`

Could you please elaborate how many is too many and how to fix it ? I couldn't find exact number in the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is not the number of entities you're retrieving, it's the fact that they're in multiple entity groups. Either do the fetch outside a transaction, or use an [XG (Cross Group) transaction](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/?csw=1#Python_Cross_group_transactions).

Comment: Yep, I missed that part about 5 entities.

Comment: At least in the Python SDK 1.7.3, there are two different error messages to the BadRequestError: "cross-group transaction need to be explicitly specified, see TransactionOptions.Builder.withXG" and "operating on too many entity groups in a single transaction". Your answer solves the former, but the latter can happen in a XG transaction, if it operates on more than 5 entity groups.

Comment: For XG transactions now, limit appears to be 25 entity groups.  See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/transactions?csw=1#What_Can_Be_Done_In_a_Transaction

Answer (score 1):

In a single transaction you can operate entities in the same entity group.

> [What Can Be Done In a Transaction](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html#What_Can_Be_Done_In_a_Transaction)

Comment: Ah yes, it's 5 for High Replication that I use. I also updated your answer.