# Can't save set of very simple entities 'cos XG transaction detected

Tags: java, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

I have following entity

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    @Basic
    private String title;
    @Basic
    private double price;
    @Basic
    private String description;
    private Map<String, Integer> map;
}
```

And then I trying to persist some number of such objects with EntityManager

```
EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      Product p = new Product();
      //call setters
      em.persist(p);
}
em.close();
```

But when call EM's close getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: operating on too many entity groups in a single transaction.
```

The question is why operating with single entity group ('Product' on my mind) this exception happens?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many objects is "too many" for in a single transaction to Google's DataStore (High Replication)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251594/how-many-objects-is-too-many-for-in-a-single-transaction-to-googles-datastore)

Comment: hmm...close to that but that answer doesn't cover my question I think. Docs says "All Datastore operations in a transaction must operate on entities in the same entity group." and in my opinion I'm working with only one group.

Comment: Why do you assume that all objects of type X are in the same Entity Group? They aren't, as that other post says. Either way the restriction is in the datastore itself, not in JPA or the JPA implementation - use that datastore and you have to work around such things

Comment: Neil Stockton, probably I made such assumption by mistake. Yep, I understand that JPA/JDO is only contract and real implementation is Datanucleous. Actually I tried to use approach with DatastoreService and raw Entities but got the same. Thanks.

Comment: This doc covers the general idea of entity groups: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency. A single kind (in this case Product) is not an Entity Group because updates within an Entity Group are limited to 1 write per second. So if you were implementing a chat server with a "Message" kind, you don't want a limit of 1 message globally per second. Instead, you could have each Message be in an Entity Group for the user who wrote it so that each user is limited to sending 1 message per second.

Comment: IMHO the datastore docs miss a clear diagram for people to visualize what an Entity Group "looks" like. I've been procrastinating over creating a blog post about this for (4) years... hope my answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

All `Product`s are not in the same entity group. Using JPA, `Product` will be your entity *kind*.
JDO & JPA hide the underlaying datastore structure, which is hierarchical, just like your OS directories for example.

Think of an entity group as a data tree, where your root entity is, well, the tree root. To provide a clear exemple, I'll add a `ProductDetail` child entity to Product. Let's say each product has many product details :

```
/** Root entity */
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    // ...

    /** Children entities */
    @OneToMany
    private List<ProductDetail> details;

}

@Entity
public class ProductDetail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
}
```

Your data would translate to the following hierarchical "schema" :

```
Product(id=1) 
|__ProductDetail(id=2)
|__ProductDetail(id=3)
|__ProductDetail(id=7)

Product(id=4)
|__ProductDetail(id=5)
|__ProductDetail(id=6)
...
```

As you can see, if your `Product` entities do not share a common parent entity (e.g. some other class holds a `@OneToMany` reference to product), each of them is considered a root entity, which means that each product is in its own entity group.

Now what the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#Java_What_can_be_done_in_a_transaction) say about transactions on entity groups :

(Using JPA, the difference between a "normal" and XG transaction is handled by the framework)

> All Datastore operations in a transaction must operate on entities in
>   the same entity group if the transaction is a single group
>   transaction, or on entities in a **maximum of five entity groups** if the
>   transaction is a cross-group (XG) transaction.

This is why creating 10 new `Product` (root) entities in a single datastore transaction will undoubtedly fail.

On the other hand, using the example above, you could create 20 `ProductDetail` entities in the same transaction if they belong to the same `Product` entity. (you could update the Product at the same time too)